# Which Marvel character is "some guy from Egypt"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, comic-adaptation, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In Captain America: The Winter Soldier, when they mention future threat for Hydra like Bruce Banner and other names (or references), they said something like "some guy from Egypt". Which character are they referring to? Is it some other Marvel character from the comics or are those just random words?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Agent Sitwell (Hydra) mentions Tony Stark, Bruce Banner, and Stephen Strange by name. We know Stark and Banner are Iron Man and the Hulk. Most comics fans will also recognize the name Stephen Strange as [Dr. Strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange), the Sorcerer Supreme. (Fans of the Marvel films will recognize him now as well, since the film *Dr. Strange* was released in November 2016.)

Sitwell also mentions "an honor student in Iowa City" and a man located in Cairo, Egypt.  I don't get the Iowa City reference, but the man in Cairo is probably a reference to [Moon Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Knight).  Moon Knight gets his origin and powers from the Egyptian moon god Khonshu.

Reference: [Captain America: The Winter Soldier’ Easter Eggs, Trivia & References](http://focusthoughts.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/captain-america-the-winter-soldier-easter-eggs-trivia-references/)

Comment: +1, if you find answer for the lowa city then don't forget to update your answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I'll keep an eye out for it, but it may be several films from now before we learn what this is a reference to.  :)

Comment: Hawkeye is from Iowa, as are Nomad and Virtue. (At least in the Marvel universe). I'm SUPER excited for a Dr. Strange movie, as that was my fave comic series growing up.

Comment: There's already a Dr. Strange movie!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHq54p8Czgg

Comment: @JohnP - Probably wouldn't be Hawkeye or Nomad, as they're both high school dropouts in 616.  Virtue is a possibility though.

Comment: @Compro01 - Yeah, I didn't think it was either of them. I honestly think that it was a random thing, not *everything* is an easter egg. :p

Comment: Nomad, @AnkitSharma .

Comment: @WillFeldman - That was a made for TV as a possible pilot, and a travesty besides.

Comment: Amadeus Cho is a more likely possibility.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I thought of that too. He's from Arizona in the comics. http://marvel.wikia.com/Amadeus_Cho_%28Earth-616%29

Comment: @RBarryYoung he is  Culver University student in MCU  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadeus_Cho#Film

Comment: Probably worth adding at this point that the Dr Strange movie has now been announced http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211837/

Answer (score 4):

##### Currently, it is unknown / unclear.

Jasper Sitwell's line is *not* "some guy from Egypt", it's "a TV anchor in Cairo". At the time of writing, it wasn't made clear who the person Sitwell was referring to.

Here's the complete dialogue:

> **Steve Rogers:** What targets?
> **Jasper Sitwell:** You!
> A TV anchor in Cairo, the under secretary of defense, a high school valedictorian in Iowa city, Bruce Banner, Stephen Strange,
> anyone who's a threat to HYDRA.
> Now, or in the future.

[Another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/19215/1006) speculates that it might be Moon Knight, but that doesn’t seem likely. While Moon Knight, aka Steven Grant or Marc Spector, has appeared in the MCU, he was not a TV anchor. Neither was he a TV anchor in the comics. Also, Steven Grant / Marc Spector is not from Cairo. Besides, Moon Knight is the avatar of a god, Khonshu, and Khonshu's "fist of vengeance". I don’t think Khonshu would approve of him being a TV anchor since it might affect Moon Knight's vengeance-related activities.

Sitwell’s line was meant to show how far-reaching and merciless HYDRA’s plan was. They were not only targeting the obvious enemies, like Steve Rogers, Bruce Banner, or Stephen Strange, but also *anyone* who could pose a problem in the future. It didn’t matter who they were, what they did, or where they lived. They were all on HYDRA’s hit list.

Answer (score 0):

I know Amadeus Cho is not from Iowa but he was an honor role student and since a possible Planet Hulk/World War Hulk may be in the works. He could be a possibility...

Answer (score -2):

If any of you have seen X-Men: Apocalypse, you would know that **Apocalypse** was around since the "Egyptian Empire", so they are probably referring to him, especially since Apocalypse has such great power and keeps coming back to fight.

Comment: It's unlikely as the rights to the X-Men universe and most of the mutant characters reside with 20th Century Fox. That's why in the MCU and the television series Marvels Agents of Shield some characters like The Scarlet Witch who were in the old continuity mutants are now either Inhumans or have powers due to Hydra experiments.